# RegEx Search & Heighlight using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, highlight

What I am looking for:

When I search for `"em"` in my search field it should highlight only containing "Em" at starting of any word. And when I search for "Em*" in my search it should highlight "Empty, Emailing, Email" etc.

now that working with my code but not in single sentence or `'p'` tag. It only works with different `'p'` or `'div'` or line though I added `"gim"` in RegEx and case insensitive also doesn't work ether. Here is my code working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rameshbaddi/3w3tw/15/

```
var searchPattern2 = new RegExp("(" + searchTerm + ")", "gmi");
    for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        if (strArray[i].match(searchPattern2)) {                            
            var replaceValue2 = "<span class='" + highlightClass + "'>" + searchTerm + "</span>";            
            alert(searchPattern2);
            var tempNode2 = document.createElement('span');
            tempNode2.innerHTML = node.nodeValue.replace(searchTerm, replaceValue2);
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(tempNode2, node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please confirm "em" is not fixed, it could be any word? eg: **xy** smallcase and **Xy** only first letter capital or it has nothing to do with the cases but with the star in the end

Comment: Can you provide some examples for your first condition :  
_When I search for "em" in my search field it should highlight only containing "Em" at starting of any word._

Comment: Yes Harpreet you are right "Em" was an example it could be any other word.

Comment: Libert in your above comment if I search for "Co" it must highlight "co" in condition and as well as "co" in containing. It must also ignore case sensitive.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is evil. Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) to highlight terms/keywords or custom regular expressions.